# Integration of PayPal in iphone app

Tags: iphone, paypal

I am facing a problem in integration of PayPal in iPhone app.

I am getting this error

> DEVELOPER ERROR: You do not have a valid PayPal issued app ID. Visit www.x.com for more information.

And it's clearly mentioned in my code that I have provided the valid id no which I retrieved when I registered my iPhone application in http://www.x.com when i run this code

```
(void)viewDidLoad{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self.navigationItem setTitle:@"Order Now"];
    self.navigationItem.hidesBackButton=NO;
    PayPal *paypal=[PayPal initializeWithAppID:@"81e6a3986bc10e03e7c4cb7f8856ad8f" forEnvironment:ENV_SANDBOX];UIButton *button1=[[PayPal getInstance]getPayButtonWithTarget:selfandAction:@selector(payWithPayPal)andButtonType:BUTTON_194x37 andButtonText:BUTTON_TEXT_PAY]; [self.view addSubview:button1];
}-(void)payWithPayPal{  PayPal *ppme=[PayPal getInstance]; PayPalPayment *payment=[[PayPal alloc]init]; payment.paymentCurrency=@"USD";
    payment.recipient=@"sa.gail.com";
    payment.paymentType=TYPE_GOODS;
    [ppme checkoutWithPayment:payment];
    [payment release];
}
```

Comment: Maybe it's because you (quote) "do not have a valid PayPal issued app ID"? Seems like you need your own API key to run this code. Just read the error.

Answer (score 0):

Use `80W284485P519543T` for AppId in the sandbox environment.